# Is there a better way to define more conventional if...then...else notations?

Tags: custom-notation

I am implementing pseudocode in Mathematica for a class I'm teaching. I would like to copy the textbook syntax which is `IF ... THEN ... ELSE ... ENDIF`. My results are not very satisfactory and my question is whether there is a way of overcoming the problems I've met.

I have used the `Notation` package as follows:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

now this is fine as far as it goes, but my first problem is that the precedence structure it creates means that compound arguments `x`, `y` and `z` have to be enclosed in brackets or the "keywords" are treated as multipliers:

```
IF (3 < 5) THEN a ELSE b ENDIF (* parses ok: returns a *)
IF  3 < 5  THEN a ELSE b ENDIF (* does not parse ok *)
```

output:
[image: Mathematica graphics]

a related issue is that I cannot split expressions over multiple lines without introducing bracketed expressions and putting the newlines within the brackets:

```
complicatedExpressionInvolvingReturns = 99998;
anotherComplicatedExpressionInvolvingReturns = Total;
IF (
  complicatedExpressionInvolvingReturns
   >= 99999
  ) THEN (
  anotherComplicatedExpressionInvolvingReturns[
   {y1, y2, y3, y4}]
  ) ELSE (

  anotherComplicatedExpressionInvolvingReturns[
   {y4, y3, y2, y1}]
  ) ENDIF
```

my second issue is that I would like `If[a,b,c]` to print as `IF a THEN b ELSE c ENDIF` but I have not found a way of using `Notation` to do this.

Is there a better way of doing this, perhaps without using the `Notation` package?

Comment: I don't know what I changed, but now `If[a,b,c]` is now printed in the form I prefer

Comment: Precedence of operators is hard coded and I don't know any way to hack it. Front End is creating box expressions, according to built-in precedence, while code is typed. You can "intercept" boxes, before they are converted to expression, using `$PreRead`, but writing robust parser that would change built-in precedence, by untangling all possible box structures, seems to be an enormous work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199595/45431) to [Seeking more verbose syntax, e.g. "Then" -> ","](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199510/45431), I thought I would try a similar approach for this question. So, define the following aliases:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAutoReplacements, "if"}] = RowBox[{
    TemplateBox[
        {},
        "if", 
        DisplayFunction->(StyleBox["IF", ShowAutoStyles->False, FontColor->GrayLevel[.5]]&),
        InterpretationFunction->("If"&)
    ],
    StyleBox["[",ShowContents->False],
    StyleBox["\[NegativeMediumSpace]", ShowContents->True]  
}];
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAutoReplacements, "then"}] = TemplateBox[
    {},
    "then",
    DisplayFunction->(StyleBox["THEN", ShowAutoStyles->False, FontColor->GrayLevel[.5]]&),
    InterpretationFunction->(","&),
    SyntaxForm->","
];
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAutoReplacements, "else"}] = TemplateBox[
    {},
    "else",
    DisplayFunction->(StyleBox["ELSE", ShowAutoStyles->False, FontColor->GrayLevel[.5]]&),
    InterpretationFunction->(","&),
    SyntaxForm->","
];
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAutoReplacements, "endif"}] = TemplateBox[
    {},
    "endif",
    DisplayFunction->(StyleBox["ENDIF", ShowAutoStyles->False, FontColor->GrayLevel[.5]]&),
    InterpretationFunction->("]"&),
    SyntaxForm->"]"
];
```

I fixed some issues with my initial answer, and I changed to input auto replacements a la Chip Hurt's answer to the linked question. It should be much more robust. An animation showing it in action:

[image]

Comment: nice.  It should be possible to combine with a Notation-style output format that matches the input.